# Beamerposter orientation

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I'm writing a poster that cannot exceed 4' to 3'. Does the default page size A0 in landscape orientation respect this dimensions ?

According to beamerposter pdf the A0 has a 2.76' x 3.90' dimensions but it doesn't mention in which orientation.

Comment: Ehm, you choose the orientation yourself, either landscape or portrait.

Comment: I know that I can choose the orientation but what are the dimensions in landscape ?  Is it 2.76' x 3.90' or this is inverted to 3.90' x 2.76' ?

Comment: The definition of landscape format is that the horizontal side is longer than the vertical side, while in portrait the vertical side is longer. So 3.9' wide, 2.76' high.

Comment: Thank you. Then the a0 in landscape orientation is enough to get me close to 4'x3'. You should change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose the orientation, landscape or portrait, of a `beamerposter` poster. The definition of landscape format is that the horizontal side is longer than the vertical one. Hence, an A0 page, which is 841mm × 1189mm in portrait, is 1189mm × 841mm in landscape. Or 3.88' × 2.76' (width × height).